# Run-time error 430: Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface"* error while looping through mails in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to loop through emails in outlook to get the "ConversationTopic" for each mail.

I have written the excel VBA code as below and for some reason it will have this *"Run-time error 430: Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface"* error. **The code is able to loop through around 1000 emails before having this error**. It did not error out immediately during the start of the loop. It will stopped at the line:

```
Debug.Print counter & vbTab & outlook_mail.class & vbTab & outlook_mail.ConversationTopic
```

If i changed the line as such it would not have any issue looping through the mail

```
Debug.Print counter & vbTab & outlook_mail.class
```

OR

```
Debug.Print counter
```

The error will only appear if this is added

```
outlook_mail.ConversationTopic
```

I've tried to google for a solution I could not find any for this error where the code stopped halfway while running.

Remark: The reason I used latebinding is to ensure all users in my office is able to use the script.

```
Sub latebinding()

Dim OutlookApp As Object
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim Outlook_namespace As Object
Set Outlook_namespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Outlook_folder As Object
Set Outlook_folder = Outlook_namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

Dim outlook_item As Object
Set outlook_item = Outlook_folder.Items

Dim outlook_mail As Object
Set outlook_mail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim outlook_attachment As Object
Set outlook_attachment = outlook_mail.Attachments

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
For Each outlook_mail In outlook_item
    If TypeName(outlook_mail) = "MailItem" Then
       Debug.Print counter & vbTab & outlook_mail.class & vbTab & outlook_mail.ConversationTopic
    End If
counter = counter + 1
Next outlook_mail

Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set Outlook_namespace = Nothing
Set outlook_attachment = Nothing
Set Outlook_folder = Nothing
Set outlook_item = Nothing
Set outlook_mail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try the [`on error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) statement?

Comment: Run the code in Outlook. If the same result you could drop Excel from the question. Update the question to tag it with Outlook and if applicable Excel.

Answer (score -1):

You may be running into the limitation mentioned in the following article

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20upper%20limit,transmit%20512%20bytes%20of%20information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20upper%20limit,transmit%20512%20bytes%20of%20information).

that: "any single call to DbgPrint will only transmit 512 bytes of information. There is also a limit to the size of the DbgPrint buffer. See DbgPrint Buffer and the Debugger for details."

Comment: How is the kernel debugger function related to VBA?